# Where can I find publicly available data about internet usage?

Tags: data-request, internet

I'm searching for a data set in the public domain that quantifies degree of internet usage on a global basis for small geographic areas.  For example is there a data set that shows total traffic (e.g. in GBs) consumed in each postal code? I'm particularly interested China.

My initial thought is that some organization like Akamai or other kind of CDN or backbone provider might have published something.  But my searches have come up empty.

Comment: Does it really have to be in the public domain, or would it suffice if the data is open? What would you like to do with the data?

Comment: check the sources here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Internet_usage

Comment: Is anything from [this answer](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4882/1511) (or its comment) of interest to you?

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is not open data, I can suggest to use also Statista. In this platform (I'm a free member), I found some data related to Internet usage in China.

**[Internet users in China 2005 - 2014.](http://www.statista.com/statistics/265140/number-of-internet-users-in-china/)**

I hope this one help you. There's also more information about Internet usage in the World Bank Database or the US Census Office.

Comment: It just says "© Statista 2015". Can you prove it is open data? Thanks!

Comment: It's not open data. That's why I suggested (not encouraged to use) this page.