# Open Data about the internet

Tags: data-request, geospatial, internet

Does anyone know where one can find (if any is available)
open data about the internet, and generally any data about tier1 infrastructure, i.e internet backbone nodes with capacity, coordinates

Also data about broad band coverage by country (and development over time).

Any data about the internet, historical, present, statistics, geographic would be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good source of "unofficial" internet data from the **[2012 Internet Census](http://internetcensus2012.bitbucket.org/paper.html)**.

> While playing around with the Nmap Scripting Engine (NSE) we discovered an amazing number of open embedded devices on the Internet. Many of them are based on Linux and allow login to standard BusyBox with empty or default credentials. We used these devices to build a distributed port scanner to scan all IPv4 addresses. These scans include service probes for the most common ports, ICMP ping, reverse DNS and SYN scans. We analyzed some of the data to get an estimation of the IP address usage.
>
> All data gathered during our research is released into the public domain for further study.

- [Hilbert Browser tool](http://internetcensus2012.bitbucket.org/hilbert/index.html)
- [Full data download](http://internetcensus2012.bitbucket.org/download.html) (568 GB torrent)
- [Image gallery](http://internetcensus2012.bitbucket.org/images.html)

[image]

---

A similar project is the [DNS Census 2013](https://dnscensus2013.neocities.org/index.html)

> The DNS Census 2013 is an attempt to provide a public dataset of registered domains and DNS records.
>
> The dataset contains about 2.5 billion DNS records gathered in the years 2012-2013.

([answer from this site](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/2142/1511))

Comment: Also check http://www.measurementlab.net/